# How to attach a JComponent to (outside) one given component's border

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I want to achieve a effect that i can add JComponents to a given component's 
(maybe a JLable)border,like picture below

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jT16.png]

I try to solve it by custom a border,and the dot is draw as a image but not a component.[Before works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45667001/attaching-images-to-jlabels-border)

But this time I want to turn the dot as an JComponent which can be attached to border.So,How could I achieve this?

Comment: A custom border might be your best bet.

Comment: I achieve a custom border by other's help,but it can't add JComponent.

Comment: @lution, If you problem is solved then don't forget to "accept" an answer by clicking on the checkmark beside the answer so people know the problem has been solved. You should do this with your previous questions as well.

Comment: @camickr OK, Thanks for advice. I'll do that. I'm still working on it right now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you didn't have much luck with your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45667001/attaching-images-to-jlabels-border), so I suggest that this time you make a special container to manage this.

Here is an example image (not to scale):

[image]

First make a `jPanel` to store and manage everything. Then you can add a `jLabel` in the middle, and then add your custom `jComponent` inside the container in the border space.

Then just make sure everything is the right size and sits in the right position and has the correct icons, and then it will look exactly the way you want like shown in your drawing.

Edit: Note that you don't actually need to add a border to the `jPanel`, the image is just showing where the `jComponent` might sit. You will probably want to set the `jPanel` background to be transparent.

Comment: (1+) this is the easiest solution which is to create a "wrapper" panel for the two components and then use a Border on the panel if required.

Comment: OK,I'll try,Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Check out [Component Border](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/09/27/component-border/).

It allows you to create a Border that contains a component. You can control the location of the component within the Border and it will manage all the insets of the border.